# Spring Cloud config with togglz

Tags: spring, spring-boot, togglz

I've configured an application with **togglz**, with the `application.properties` externalized in a Spring Boot Config server. When I update a feature status on `application.properties` in the server and make a call to `/actuator/refresh` they return the feature changes, but the application doesn't change the status of the feature. If I restart the application the status changes.

Does anyone know if it is possible disable a feature without restart application, and didn't use togglz console?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Disable a feature in a database. If you are using default values: table "togglz" column "feature_enabled"